# How to pass query variable from soql into loop

Tags: apex, callout, loop, apex-variable, variable-scope

I am trying to bulkify a callout where I want to pass the recordtype in my loop but I get:

> Error: Variable does not exist: RecordType

If I try `public RecordType personAccountRecordType` I get public not allowed on locals

Below is my code

```
 RecordType personAccountRecordType =  [SELECT Id FROM RecordType WHERE Name = 'Person Account' and SObjectType = 'Account'][0].RecordType;

            List<Account> persAccount  = new List<Account>();

            for(integer x=0; x<guestsClass.size();x++){
            Account acc = new Account(lastname=guestsClass[0].lastName, RecordType = personAccountRecordType);
            persAccount.add(acc);
            }
            insert persAccount;
```

Update:

```
          Http http = new Http();
        HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
        //Catch is not needed since soql's cant be empty in this case 
        os = [SELECT Url__c, ApiKey__c, agencyUid__c FROM Orbirental_Service__c LIMIT 1]; 

        request.setEndpoint(os[0].Url__c +'v1/guests?agencyUid='+os[0].agencyUid__c);
        request.setMethod('GET');
        request.setHeader('X-ORBIRENTAL-APIKEY', os[0].ApiKey__c);
        HttpResponse response = http.send(request);
        if (response.getStatusCode() == 200) {
                    System.debug(response.getBody());
            List<or_guestsJSON> guestsClass = or_guestsJSON.parse(response.getBody());
            System.debug(guestsClass);
            System.debug('guestsClass[0].lastName '+guestsClass[0].lastName);
            Id personAccountRecordType =  [SELECT Id FROM RecordType WHERE Name = 'Person Account' and SObjectType = 'Account'][0].Id;
            List<Account> persAccount  = new List<Account>();
            for(integer x=0; x<guestsClass.size();x++){
            Account acc = new Account(name=guestsClass[0].lastName, RecordTypeId = personAccountRecordType);
            persAccount.add(acc);
            }
            insert persAccount;
            system.debug('persoon '+persAccount);
}
```

ERROR:INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY, Record Type ID: this ID value isn't valid for the user: 0000000000000: [RecordTypeId]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple of issues here on your current code:

```
RecordType personAccountRecordType =  [SELECT Id FROM RecordType WHERE Name = 'Person Account' and SObjectType = 'Account'][0].RecordType;

Account acc = new Account(lastname=guestsClass[0].lastName, RecordType = personAccountRecordType);
```

1. `RecordType` is not a *Type* for variable declaration
2. `[0].RecordType` -- there's no column named `RecordType` on the Object itself.
3. While assigning a record type for Account, you need to use `RecordTypeId`

---

Your code for retrieving the record type and assigning it to Account should look like as below:

```
// get the Record Type's id from here
Id personAccountRecordType =  [SELECT Id FROM RecordType WHERE Name = 'Person Account' and SObjectType = 'Account'][0].Id;

// assign it to Account. 
// notice the field name here for record type assignment, it is RecordTypeId
Account acc = new Account(
    lastname=guestsClass[0].lastName, 
    RecordTypeId = personAccountRecordType);
```

Comment: I get the same error in my loop missing ID. The purpose is to add multiple accounts to a list with the same recordtype person account.

Comment: It's tough to understand without looking at it.

Comment: I added an update to clarify

Comment: What is the error you are getting? It must be unrelated as you don't have the complete code. As for just fetching the record type id and assigning it to account, that will just work.

Comment: I added the complete code and error I run this from anonymouse window.

Comment: This is a different issue as compared to what you had mentioned initially in the original question. You may like to open another one. In the forum, we try to keep issues limited to one question. However, just by looking at this, it seems that your user profile (or the user profile executing the code) does not have the record type assigned to it.

Comment: That's what I had suspected. Glad that it worked out for you.